# How can my regular expression supports many languages like chinese ,japanese,French etc

Tags: javascript, regex

i am new to java scripting .I have written a regular expression which allows username or email address as a input with some conditions like 
Should accept 6-50 characters
doesnot allows space or blank
should not allow 2 `@` symbols & can accept more than 1 `.` (dot) & `_` (underscore).
This is my regular expression.

```
var regExpPattern = /^(?=.{6,50}$)([\w._]+@?[\w.]*)$/;
```

Can any one give me an idea how can i make my regular expression supports multi languages like spanish, chinese, french etc..
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is your regex currently failing for French email addresses?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse email. `<input type="email" />` does it for you.

Comment: Also legitimate email addresses can be much longer than 50 characters.

Comment: sorry Pointy this regular expression has written according to my project requirement

Comment: @Pointy With respect to your comment what is the reason behind not accepting the `French email addresses`, is it the `\w` that doesn't support it?

Comment: @RajeshPaul ah yes that may be true - JavaScript regular expressions are pitiful from an i18n standpoint

Comment: @Pointy you said may be!!! I just thought it is the probable reason behind such problem.
But I actually wanted to know your standpoint for that specific problem. why it would forbid french emails? Will be glad to get a clear logic from you.

Comment: @RajeshPaul well the problem seems to be that `\w` only matches half the first "Latin" Unicode code page. Things like "ç" don't match, which is really dumb.

Comment: @RajeshPaul [here is the relevant part of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.2.12)

Comment: @Pointy thanx for this to the point info. Must also help the OP realise the root of the problem.

Comment: So, the full spec for the structure of a valid email address is surprisingly complex. You need to decide just how complete you want your implementation to be. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for an example of a 'complete' address regexp...but that one only implements RFC 5322. UTF-8 support was added in RFC 6531, and that's what you'll want for your 'multi-language support'.

Comment: instead of \w, you can use  \p{L} with the unicode flag.  \p{L} will match any letter from any language  see other cases @ https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode

Answer (score 0):

To cover other languages, you can use the Unicode codes/ranges for the special characters.

As an example (with Perl) for Japanese:

```
if ($text =~ m/[\x{3041}-\x{3096}]/) { print $text; }
```

This finds all hiragana in a text string, Unicode code range being: **[\x3041-\x3096]**

So it would find any of these in a string:

> ぁ あ ぃ い ぅ う ぇ え ぉ お か が き ぎ く ぐ け げ こ ご さ ざ し じ す ず せ ぜ そ ぞ た だ ち ぢ っ
>   つ づ て で と ど な に ぬ ね の は ば ぱ ひ び ぴ ふ ぶ ぷ へ べ ぺ ほ ぼ ぽ ま み む め も ゃ や ゅ ゆ
>   ょ よ ら り る れ ろ ゎ わ ゐ ゑ を ん ゔ ゕ ゖ  ゙ ゚ ゛ ゜ ゝ ゞ ゟ

Give it a try on [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) for example, this:

```
\u3041
```

on the above set of hiragana, would find:

> ぁ

Same goes for other languages.